# Conda-Build with Git repo as source: can I include only some files of the repo?

Tags: package, conda, conda-build

I'm sorry if this question is stupid but I'm very new to conda and I cannot find relevant informations about this problem.

I have to build a small package with conda-build. The package **only needs to include two python files, but they are located inside a much bigger git repo**. Is there a way in my meta.yaml to specify that the source is this repo but **only files A and B needs to be included** in the package?

I've set up the meta.yaml with the source field pointing to the repo, but I could not find ways to specify that only some files need to be included in the final package.

Comment: Where do you expect these Python files to be stored? Is this a proper Python package or just some scripts? One can use a `build.sh` to specifically copy files from the source folders (with be pwd), to a package location (`${PREFIX}`). E.g., the Bioconda STAR recipe simply copies pre-built binaries from the tarball to the environment (see https://github.com/bioconda/bioconda-recipes/tree/4754cd022f9661672e2532176cdd20f15c7dc1ac/recipes/star)